# python random numbers and comparison

Tags: python, random, numbers

I'm a new programmer and just starting off with Python. I have the following 2 questions, however, I decided to put them in one post.

1. When asking to input age, how do I force the program to only accept numbers?
2. The concept is that after the user has entered their age, the program would pick a random number between 1 and 100 and compare it to the user input, returning either "I'm older than you", "I'm younger than you" or "we are the same age".

   ```
   # Print Welcome Message
   print("Hello World")
   # Ask for Name
   name = input("What is your name? ")
   print("Hello " + str(name))
   # Ask for Age
   age = input("How old are you? ")
   print("Hello " + str(name) + ", you are " + str(age) + " years old.")
   random.randint(1, 100)
   ```

Comment: Thank you all, I ended up using a combination of your answers and managed to get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you can try this simply.

```
import random
name = input("What is your name? ")
print("Hello " + str(name))
while True :
    try :
        age = int(input("How old are you? "))
        break
    except :
        print("Your entered age is not integer. Please try again.")
print("Hello " + str(name) + ", you are " + str(age) + " years old.")
randNumber=random.randint(1, 100)
if randNumber > age :
    print("I am older than you")
if randNumber < age :
    print("I am younger than you")
else :
    print("we are the same age")
```

Only made few changes to existing code with modifications asked.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following

```
import random
# Print Welcome Message
print("Hello World")
# Ask for Name
name = input("What is your name? ")
print("Hello " + str(name))
# Ask for Age
while True:   # only numbers
    try: 
        age = int(input("How old are you? "))
    except:
        pass

print("Hello " + str(name) + ", you are " + str(age) + " years old.")
t=random.randint(1, 100)
if t==age:
    print("we are the same age")   #compare ages
if t<age:
    print("I'm younger than you")
if t>age:
    print("I'm older than you")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import random
# Print Welcome Message
print("Hello World")
# Ask for Name
name = input("What is your name? ")
print("Hello " + str(name))
# Ask for Age
while True:
    try:
        age = int(input("How old are you? "))
    except ValueError:
        pass 
print("Hello " + str(name) + ", you are " + str(age) + " years old.")

my_random = random.randint(1, 100)
if  my_random > age:
    print("Im older than you")
elif my_random < age:
    print("I'm younger than you")
else:
    print("We are the same age")
```

Includ a try block around the age part. If the user inputs an non-int answer then it will just pass. I then saved the random int that you generated it and compared it to the age to find if the random int was greater than the age.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your **first question**, use `int()` as such:

```
age = int(input("How old are you? "))
```

This will raise an exception (error) if the value is not an integer.

---

To answer your **second question**, you may store the random number in a variable and use it in comparison to the user's age, using conditional statements (`if`, `elif`, `else`). So for instance:

```
random.seed()  # you need to seed the random number generator
n = random.randint(1, 100)

if n < age:
    print("I am younger than you.")
elif n > age:
    print("I am older than you.")
else:
    print("We are the same age.")
```

I hope this answers your question. You can refer to the [official Python docs](https://docs.python.org/) for more info on conditional statements.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you should convert the variable age into integer. For example:

age = input("How old are you?")

age = int(age)

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the 1st question.

x = int(input("Enter any number: "))

To force the program to enter number add int in your input statement as above.